# Does NetLogo filter generate the results in the same order as the source list?

Tags: netlogo

I have a list of lists which is used as a FIFO queue (using lput):

```
set mylist  [[-8.5 0] [1.5 0] [-7.5 1] [0.5 1] [-8.5 2] [1.5 2] [-5.5 3] [2.5 3] [-5.5 4] [2.5 4] [1.5 5] [1.5 6] [-8.5 7] [3.5 7]]
```

I can filter the list, extracting those items which have -8.5 in the first position:

```
show filter [item 0 ? = -8.5] mylist
```

[[-8.5 0] [-8.5 2]  [-8.5 7]]

Likewise, I can filter the list, extracting those items which have 3 in the second position:

```
show filter [item 1 ? = 3] mylist
```

[[-5.5 3] [2.5 3]]

Does filter guarantee that the results will maintain the same order as those in the original list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, a list is ordered and filter (and sublist etc) preserve the order